# Integer Linear Programming formulation for Test Cover?

Tags: linear-programming

The Test Cover problem can be defined as follows:

Suppose we have a set of `n` diseases and a set of `m` tests we can perform to check for symptoms. We also are given the following:

- an `n`x`n` matrix `A` where `A[i][j]` is a binary value representing the result of running the `j`th test on a patient with the the `i`th disease (1 indicates a positive result, 0 indicates negative);
- the cost of running test `j`, `c_j`; and that
- any patient will have exactly one disease

The task is to find a set of tests that can uniquely identify each of the the `n` diseases at minimal cost.

---

This problem can be formulated as an Integer Linear Program, where we want to minimize the objective function `\sum_{j=1}^{m} c_j x_j`, where `x_j` = 1 if we choose to include test `j` in our set, and 0 otherwise.

My question is:

> What is the set of linear constraints for this problem?

Incidentally, I believe this problem is NP-hard (as is Integer Linear Programming in general).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let `T` be the matrix that results from deleting the `j`th column of `A` for all `j` such that `x_j` = 0.

Then choosing a set of tests that can uniquely distinguish any two diseases is equivalent to ensuring that every row of `T` is unique.

Observe that two rows `k` and `l` are identical if and only if `(T[k][j] XOR T[l][j]) = 0` for all `j`.

So, the constraints we want are

> `\sum_{j=1}^{m}  x_j(A[k][j] XOR A[l][j]) >= 1`
>
> for all `1 <= k <= m` and `1 <= l <= 1` such that `k != l`.

Note that the constraints above are linear, since we can just pre-compute the coefficient `(A[k][j] XOR A[l][j])`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am correct you just need  to ensure

```
\sum_j x_j.A_ij >= 1 forall i
```

Comment: But then if any x_j = 0, that sum is 0. So those constraints force us to choose every single test, which of course cannot be right... Unless I've misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Not really, if an `x_j.A_ij` is 1, then the sum is at least one, which is what you look for.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. But, that is still not correct. Consider the case where we have two diseases, D1 and D2, and two tests, T1 and T2, such that both D1 and D2 return positive for T1, and negative for T2. Then choosing x_1 = 1 and x_2 = 0 satisfies your constraints, yet we cannot distinguish the two diseases.

Comment: ok my bad I did not understand properly the formulation of your problem